# How to make svg image fits to parent container

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using for the first time the svg `<image>` tag. I use this tag in order to apply a gray filter on the picture (thank you IE).

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <image  xlink:href="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/00ffd5.png" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the scss :

```
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 220px;

  background-color: blue;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

I want to fit the image to the parent's container. Something like background: cover in css. Does anybody have an idea ?

You can check it out at : https://codepen.io/seabon/pen/QvBBrd

[image]

The blue background is for `div.item`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATED**

- Add `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` attributes.
- Add [**`preserveAspectRatio`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) <sup>**1**</sup>   with value of **`none`**<sup>**2**</sup> .

  > **none** do not force uniform scaling. Scale the graphic content of the given element non-uniformly if necessary such that the element's bounding box exactly matches the viewport rectangle.
  >   *Note: if `<align>` is none, then the optional `<meetOrSlice>` value is ignored*.

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vf6j1z2y/3/) - tested on Chrome, FF and IE11

```css
.item { position: relative; width: 20%; height: 220px; background-color: blue; }
svg { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <svg id="theSVG" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="//dummyimage.com/400x400/000/00ffd5.png" preserveAspectRatio="none" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

---

**Notes:**

1. The use of this `preserveAspectRatio` attribute was initially offered by another answer - *I forgot the user, many thanks to him though*- and it got deleted, in that answer the attribute was `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` but without using the `width="100%" height="100%"`, except the ones in CSS which don't work except [*partially, because if you resize the view larger the blue background will start to show up*] in Chrome as stated in [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44020863/2081719) answer. this [**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bk4634vp/2/) represents how that nice answer was.
2. **`none`** does *not* force the scale to be uniformed, it may squish or stretch the image to make it fits, While it doesn't make any difference in the OP case, if Keeping aspect ratio is needed, then any of [the other](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio#Usage_context) `Min`, `Mid` and `Max` for `x` or `y` could be used but it must be accompanied with `slice` only and not `meet`.

Comment: FYI: the answer suggesting `preserveAspectRatio` was posted by [Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395910/terry).

Answer (score 4):

Just set an appropriate `viewBox` attribute on your SVG.  Then set `preserveAspectRatio` to a value that uses the `slice` option, instead of the default `meet`.  For example:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
```

This is equivalent to CSS's `background-size: cover`.

BTW, setting `width` and `height` of the `<image>` via CSS will only work on Chrome right now.  You'll need to assign those in the SVG if you want your example to work in other browsers.

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 220px;

  background-color: blue;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
        <image xlink:href="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/00ffd5.png"
               width="400" height="400"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to replicate this setup, and I don't believe it will achieve the "background cover" effect the poster is asking for. For me, it maintains its aspect ratio but will not extend past the bounds of the viewbox in order to fill the available space, the way a background-size cover bg image would.

Comment: I missed the OPs request for "cover". I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use image tab there is my solution with CSS:

```
.item-image{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background: url(https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/00ffd5.png) center;
background-size: 100% 100% ;
}
```

- don't forget create div with the item-image class, between svg tags.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PiotrBryla/pen/MmBqMd)

[There](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=200px) is a website where you can play with background-size. You can change the background of each element by assigning an id to div and add an attribute with JS.

Comment: Thank you but I have to use the <image> tag in order to apply a gray filter on it

Comment: This will stretch the image.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with the same. The image sourcegraphic might not be your best option.

If you want cover fit try using a background image as you normally would and apply a filter to the element by referencing an SVG filter.

**Example**

```
.bg_img {
    -webkit-filter: url(#distort_slider_filter);
    filter: url(#distort_slider_filter);
}
```

**Demo:** 
https://codepen.io/Andersdn11/pen/QXWmgr

Comment: That crappy browser.. How important is it? It might be a fair tradeoff and call it graceful degradation in your instance?